# Magento Override Downloadable links.phtml and Links.php with Extension

Tags: php, magento

I am building a little Magento Extension that overrides in the Downloadable Adminhtml Section the links.phtml and Links.php but it doesnt work correctly :-(.

Thats my code:

app/code/local/MyModule/ModuleName/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyModule_ModuleName>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </MyModule_ModuleName>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <downloadable>
        <rewrite>
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_downloadable_links>MyModule_ModuleName_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Downloadable_Links</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_tab_downloadable_links>
        </rewrite>
      </downloadable>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyModule/ModuleName/Block/Rewrite/MyModule_ModuleName_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Downloadable_Links.php

```
class MyModule_ModuleName_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Downloadable_Links extends Mage_Downloadable_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Downloadable_Links
    {
      /**
       * Class constructor
       *
       */
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('mymodulemodulename/product/edit/downloadable/links.phtml');
    }     
}
```

app/etc/modules/MyModule_ModuleName.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <MyModule_ModuleName>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </MyModule_ModuleName>
  </modules>
</config>
```

If I open a product (Downloadable Product) in the Admin Section, I only the left Navigation Links with full width and nothing else. If I click on one Link like General, Price or DownloadableOptions nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? :-(

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your config.xml file. You are trying to override adminhtml block with your custom block that resides in frontend. So this is creating problem.
Please change this code:

        
 MyModule_ModuleName_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Downloadable_Links

with below code:

MyModule_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Downloadable_Links